# Combining 2 working GREP expressions into one

Tags: shell

I have a file that has log entries such as:

Format 1:

```
INFO  07 May 2015 15:24:35,146 vert.x-worker-thread-19:40422-6 [28782710226944/personWebApiMultiPass:UnfilteredNamedEntityPipelineProcessor:unfilteredNamedEntityPipelineProcessor] [oiq.contentdigestion.PipelineProcessor] - COMPLETE >10000ms [16992ms]: http://example1.com/long-url/etc.html
```

Format 2:

```
INFO  07 May 2015 15:24:34,648 vert.x-worker-thread-12:40464-2 [28782710226945/personWebApiMultiPass:HighlyAssociatedEntitiesPipelineProcessorInternal] [oiq.contentdigestion.PipelineProcessor] - COMPLETE [0 ms]: http://example2.com/yet-another-long-url/etc.html
```

Note: The difference beteween 2 lines is the time format within the square braces `[]`.

To match the format 1 lines, I used the following grep command:

```
grep -E "\[[0-9]* ms\]" filename
```

To match the format 2 lines, I used the following grep command:

```
grep -E "\[[0-9]*ms\]" filename
```

Can anyone help with the grep expression to match both format lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the space optional. You can do this using the `?` character, which means `*zero or one* match in Extended Regular Expression mode:

```
grep -E '\[[0-9]+ ?ms\]' file
```

Using EREs, the `+` character means *one or more* which makes more sense in this context.

Alternatively, in basic mode:

```
grep '\[[0-9]\{1,\} *ms\]' file
```

Here I have used `\{1,\}` as a replacement for the `+`, which is not POSIX-compliant (although you can use `\+` with GNU grep). I also used a `*` (*zero or more*) to match the optional space. I guess that you're not concerned whether there are zero, one or more spaces in your case. If you wanted to be strict, you could change it to `\{0,1\}`.

Comment: @user2862093 you should escape the outer `\[` and `\]` as I have done in my answer, otherwise the meaning of the regex changes.